# Table Column Resize Issue

Tags: html, css, graph

I am having a problem resizing my table column. When I put my bar graph and image slideshow side by side in separate divs, this causes the table column to shrink. The image below shows what it looks like. The first table column is supposed to be like a key for the colours in the graph. I've tried adjusting the width in the CSS, but it resizes the graph width, not the table column width. Is there something wrong with the CSS, or is the divs in the HTML that are causing the problem? Appreciate the help.

[image]

HTML

```
    <div class="graph">
      <div class="positive">34%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph">
      <div class="negative">23%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph">
      <div class="mixed">43%</div>
    </div>

    <table id="tableSentiment" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="tableColour" style="background-color: #1E8449"></td>
    <td>Positive</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="tableColour" style="background-color: #CB4335"></td>
    <td>Negative</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="tableColour" style="background-color: #E67E22"></td>
    <td>Mixed</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.graph
{
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
}

.positive, .negative, .mixed
{
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.positive 
{
  width: 34%; 
  background-color: #1E8449;
}

.negative 
{
  width: 23%; 
  background-color: #CB4335;
}

.mixed 
{
  width: 43%; 
  background-color: #E67E22;
}

#tableSentiment
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 100%;
  left: 10%;
}

#tableColour
{
  width: 15%;
}
```

Comment: could you post an image or sketch of what youre trying to accomplish ? Cause maybe you can achieve what you want with a grid layout:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I had a correct interpretation of what you're trying to achieve the you might actually wan to use a grid layout. What I did was wrap your elements inside divs, then I placed those divs inside a Container div. That container div `.grid-container` will have the `display: grid` the rest is just configuring the columns and rows.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50% ;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  column-gap: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.graph-container{
  grid-column: 1 / span 1; /**Configure the column*/
  grid-row: 1 /span 1; /**Configure the row*/
}

.graph-container{
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 /span 1;
}

.imageContainer{
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 /span 2;
}

.graph {

  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
}

.imga{
 width: 100%;
}

.positive,
.negative,
.mixed {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.positive {
  width: 34%;
  background-color: #1E8449;
}

.negative {
  width: 23%;
  background-color: #CB4335;
}

.mixed {
  width: 43%;
  background-color: #E67E22;
}

#tableSentiment {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%; /*Adjust the table so it will fit inside its parent container*/
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%; 
  left: 10%;
}

#tableColour {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container"> <!--Main container -->
  <div class="graph-container"> <!-- Container for your graphs-->
    <div class="graph">
      <div class="positive">34%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph">
      <div class="negative">23%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph">
      <div class="mixed">43%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div id="sentimentContainer"> <!--Container for your guide-->
    <table id="tableSentiment" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td id="tableColour" style="background-color: #1E8449"></td>
        <td>Positive</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="tableColour" style="background-color: #CB4335"></td>
        <td>Negative</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="tableColour" style="background-color: #E67E22"></td>
        <td>Mixed</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <div class="imageContainer"> <!--Container for your image-->
  <img class="imga" src="https://c.pxhere.com/photos/7d/c2/adorable_animal_blur_bokeh_cat_cat_face_close_up_cute-1492927.jpg!d" />
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: This is great, it works and displays nicely on my page. Thank you!